# how can I update android widgets with service in background

Tags: android, service, widget, android-widget, alarmmanager

I have trouble in widgets,and I need you help.
I want to update widgets in 1 minute.What the way I used is set a timer with alarmmanger to start a service to update widgets.But it doesn't work in the background,only work when the mainactivity is alive.

following is my codes.

**myWidgetProvider:**

```
private static final int UPDATE_DURATION = 60 * 1000; 

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(),UPDATE_DURATION,createPendingIntent(context));

    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++){
        int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.quotes_layout);
        views.setTextColor(R.id.quotes_textview,Color.WHITE);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId,views);
    }

}


private PendingIntent createPendingIntent(Context context){
    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context,TimerService.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context,0,alarmIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    return pendingIntent;
}


@Override
public void onDisabled(Context context) {
    super.onDisabled(context);

    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    manager.cancel(createPendingIntent(context));
}
```

**myService:**

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    //Internet request and update widgets

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
     public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
         RemoteViews remoteView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.app_widget);
    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.coffee_quote, getRandomQuote(context))  //changing text...
    ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteView);
     }
```

use above code to update the text from service and you can do others things like setting color in text in textview. or control its visibility.

and instead of background service u can use [foreground](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services) service or [JobService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobService) , both work even the mainActivity is destroyed. but JobService is more optimized for android 9+.

Comment: even better solution :P.